# React: Update variable in different components on event

Tags: reactjs

I'm fairly new to react and I'm probably using a wrong concept since I'm trying to solve a simple problem.

Imagine a parent component with multiple children:

- OverviewComponent (parent)
- DetailsComponent (child)
- EditComponent (child)
- HistoryComponent (child)

The parent holds all three children. The data displayed in the three children is the same object.

What I'm trying to do is to update the data in the children based on a click in the HistoryComponent. Think of an list of objects inside the HistoryComponents. When a user clicks on a list entry, the DetailsComponent should show data based on the object selected inside the HistoryComponent. Same goes for the EditComponent.

I've got two ideas to solve this:

1. Pass a prop with the objectsId from the parent to all children and if the user selects a different object in the HistoryComponent, use a function which gets also passed as prop to update the props.objectId inside the OverviewComponent (parent) --> Problem: Code looks ugly and I can't get it to work
2. Use useState and useEffect. --> Problem: Due to the async nature of useState, this won't update the property immediatly in all child components.

How do I solve this problem? This seems like a very trivial problem/concept most react apps use, so this can't be that complicated, huh?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you try to `useContext`? can you post a small codesandbox example?

Comment: A small codesandbox example would be great to see why your code doesn't work, once we figure that out then optimizing it would be easy.

Comment: See the react docs for [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). TL;DR you colocate the common state in the closest ancestor and pass the state and state updater functions down as props to the children. The React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) is an extension of this pattern. Please do edit your post to include a [mcve] for what you've tried though as SO isn't a code writing service and we can't help diagnose or debug code we can't see.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes is better to start off with a working example.
here's an implementation of what I think is your concept - just 3 components: Overview, History & Details.
Currently selected item is held in the state `selected` and `setSelected` is passed as a prop to the `History` component to adjust `selected` as user clicks an item.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {useState} from "react";

const history = [
    {
        id: 0,
        name: 'entry 0',
        details: 'details for entry 0'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'entry 1',
        details: 'details for entry 1'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'entry 2',
        details: 'details for entry 2'
    }
]

function Details({item}) {
    return (
        item && <div>
            <p>item details:</p>
            <h2>{item.name}</h2>
            <p>{item.details}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

function History({items, setSelected}) {

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setSelected(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="history">History</label>
            <br/>
            <select id="history" name="history" size={4} onChange={handleChange}>
                {items.map(e => <option value={e.id} key={e.id}>{e.name}</option>)}
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}

function Overview({items}) {

    const [selected, setSelected] = useState();

    return(
        <div>
            <p>selected entry: {selected ?? 'none'}</p>
            <History items={items} setSelected={setSelected}/>
            <Details item={selected ? items[selected] : null}/>
        </div>
    )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Overview items={history}/>
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

somewhere in you index.html you have to put `<div id="root"></div>` as an anchor point for your React app

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-cdn-dwxuyr

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Will the change of 'selected' take effect inside the Details immediatly, once I trigger it from the <History />?

Comment: yes, it's instant. you can see for yourself: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-cdn-dwxuyr

Answer (score 1):

What you mentioned can be easily done by `useContext` hook.
First create a context :

```
export const MyListContext = createContext();
```

Then In `OverviewComponent` use that context:

```
function OverviewComponent() {
  const [myList, setMyList] = useState([]);
  return ( 
    <MyListContext.Provider value={{myList, setMyList}}>
      <DetailsComponent />
      <EditComponent />
      <HistoryComponent />
    </MyListContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

**Ps**: `myList` and `setMyList` can be accessible in any component which is wrapped into `MyListContext.Provider`. If each one of them changes `myList` value (using `setMyList`), then every one gets updated.

You can use the defined context in child components like so:

```
function HistoryComponent() {
  const { myList, setMyList } = useContext(MyListContext);
  return (
    <button onClick={()=>setMyList(["this is an example."])}>updateList</button>
  )
}
```